# Babel transpile systemjs module skip specific modules?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a vanilla Cordova app. But the fact that it is a Cordova app should not matter, just think of it as a vanilla web site. Most scripts right now are loaded in through the `<script>` tags. Recently added gulp and Babel transpilation with `env` preset. I want to begin to migrate to ES2015 module supported by Systemjs. However, because there are lots of legacy codes (and some part I have no idea what it is doing, lots of globals, etc), I want to migrate to ES2015 module on a file-by-file basis. Is there a way to ask Babel not to do module transpilation for some files (but best if transpile for other ES2015 features)? It would be useful if it doesn't mess with files which do not have any `export` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `ignore` or `only` babel.rc options found here: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/#options

Comment: With this I cannot say I want a file to transpile to ES2015, but don't make it a module right?

Comment: The reason for this is because I've already used some ES2015 features, so it may be kind of hard to find exactly which files they are in.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your babel build task into two parts. First pass compiles all files without converting modules, the second only applies the module transformation to a list of files that you manually update.

Here's what that might look like with gulp and [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter):

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const babel = require("gulp-babel");
const filter = require("gulp-filter");

const esmReady = ["src/somefile.js"];

gulp.task("default", () => {
  const f = filter(esmReady, { restore: true });
  gulp
    .src("src/*.js")
    .pipe(
      babel({
        presets: [["env", { modules: false }]]
      })
    )
    .pipe(f)
    .pipe(
      babel({
        plugins: ["transform-es2015-modules-systemjs"]
      })
    )
    .pipe(f.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```